# Время жизни сессии уменьшить

Tags: сессия, php

Привет.Есть 2 параметра которые отвечают за время жизни сессии

-session.cookie_lifetime http://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

-session.cookie_lifetime

Експеремент:
**index.php**

```
    session_start();
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1);
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',1);
    $_SESSION['user']='root';

<?php
$user=isset($_SESSION['user']) ? $_SESSION['user'] : 'delete session';
echo 'hello'.$user;

?>
        <a href="away.php" >away.php</a>
```

**away.php**

```
session_start();
$user=isset($_SESSION['user']) ? $_SESSION['user'] : 'delete session';

echo 'hello'.$user;

echo '<a href="index.php">index</a>';
var_dump(ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime'));//1440 почему не 1?
```

Установил я время жизни 1 секунду 
при переходе на страницу away.php $_SESSION['user']='root' не удалилось

Comment: **session.gc_probability integer**

> session.gc_probability в сочетании с session.gc_divisor определяет вероятность запуска функции сборщика мусора (gc, garbage collection). По умолчанию равна 1.

**session.gc_divisor integer**

> session.gc_divisor в сочетании с session.gc_probability вероятность запуска функции сборщика мусора (gc, garbage collection) при каждой инициализации сессии. Вероятность рассчитывается как gc_probability/gc_divisor, т.е. 1/100 означает, что функция gc запускается в одном случае из ста, или 1% при каждом запросе. session.gc_divisor по умолчанию имеет значение 100.

Comment: т.о. лучше просто записывать в сессию текущее время и сверять его собственной логикой на предмет lifetime, истекло - удалить данные из сессии.

Comment: второй способ про который вы говорили я уже сделал.Хочется разобратся с этим.

Comment: ну вот и сказано в документации, что эффект вами наблюдаемый, происходит от того что вероятность удаления записи сессии(запуска  сборщика мусора) равна по умолчанию 1/100, т.е. если вы после того, как прошла 1 секунда, запустите php ~100 раз сессия будет действительно удалена.

Comment: Ну я могу поставить gc_probability=100 или это будет сильно грузить сервер? 100/100=100% .

Comment: На SO все только про этот способ и говорят http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960

Comment: на SO в принятом ответе как раз и говорят, что это плохая идея протухать сессию подобным образом, гораздо лучше это делать собственной логикой. Внимательно прочитайте со слов **So to conclude: The best solution is to implement a session timeout on your own. Use a simple time stamp that denotes the time of the last activity (i.e. request) and update it with every request:**

Comment: Установку времени сессии нужно до старта сессии